# Why is ob.constructor.prototype == ob.__proto__

Tags: javascript, prototype

Say if we create an object

```
var ob = {}
```

When I check

```
ob.constructor.prototype == ob.__proto__
```

both are same how is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ob` is a plain object, so its constructor (that is, `obj.constructor`) is `Object`. The `__proto__` points to the internal prototype of something, and the internal prototype of a plain object is `Object.prototype`.

If you're somewhat familiar with prototypal inheritance, the behavior might be more understandable if `ob` was created with `new` (just to see how it works - you shouldn't actually use `new Object`):

```js
var ob = new Object();
console.log(ob.constructor.prototype == ob.__proto__);
// same as
console.log(ob.constructor.prototype == Object.prototype);
// same as
console.log(Object.prototype == Object.prototype);
```

The same sort of behavior can be seen for anything created with `new` - its `constructor.prototype` will be its `__proto__`:

```js
class Foo {}

const f = new Foo();

console.log(f.constructor.prototype == f.__proto__);
// same as
console.log(f.constructor.prototype == Foo.prototype);
// same as
console.log(Foo.prototype == Foo.prototype);
```